# Regular expressions : find all div tags which contain tag img

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I need to find and replace all div tags which contains tag img, I tried some regular expression without succes :( 
this is an example of a regular expression that I tried:
`/(<div class="indicator"[^<]*>.*<img[^>]*>[^<]*</div>)/g` 
Help please

Thank you

Comment: And what do you want to do when a div contains a div which contains an image ? Are you sure you don't want to parse instead of using a regex ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions. They're not appropriate tool to do it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answers

Comment: I have to remove all divs witch a specific class and contains a tag img, in the case of nested divs I only remove the last one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the potential of having nested div div image like dystroy said then it can't be done properly with a regular expression as it's not actually a regular language. Probably you should use DOM. This is relevant: 
[How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml)

Answer (score 1):

Better not to try parsing HTML using RegEx, it can be error prone. Using [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) you can do:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$nodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
for($i=0; $i < $nodeList->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodeList->item($i);
    $children = $node->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) { 
       if ($child->nodeName == 'img') {
          echo "DIV tag contains IMG tag\n";
          break;
       }
    }
}
```